# Does 一度 have any meanings besides "once"?

Tags: meaning

I've seen 一度 used in ways that I'm not sure corresponds to the meaning "once". Specifically, I mean when it is used adverbially without any particle attached. For instance this line:

> 一度この農村で旅の準備をしましょう

Does it simply mean "let's make travel preparations in this farming village once"? The "once" doesn't seem to be adding much, if that's the case. Going off the definitions [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/12595/meaning/m0u/) and [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/186059/meaning/m0u/) I don't see how else I can understand it. Can someone shed some light on this?

(Context: In the story I was reading a party of travelers had just arrived at a town early in their journey and was looking to acquire any supplies they needed then head off.)

Comment: Please make sure you include any context that's necessary to answer your question.  If you find out that more context is necessary after posting, please don't leave that context in a comment – always use the 'edit' button to add it to your question.  Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me quote the dictionary entry you saw:

> １ 1回。いっぺん。ひとたび。「―おいでください」「一生に―の体験」
>
> ２ （副詞的に用いて）いったん。ひとたび。もし。「―食べたら忘れられない味」→一度に

In this case, **いったん** (一旦) in 2 applies the best. Check the meaning of 一旦 [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/13469/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%93/).

I'd say "for the time being" here. "for some time" or "for a while" would also be OK.

Comment: I considered so but that entry kinda confused me. Going off the example I thought it just meant "once" as in, for example, "once it starts it can't stop". That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Comment: The 一度 in OP's sentence 一度この農村で旅の準備をしましょう is definition #1 (sometime in the future) , not #2 (Once you've done~~, ...).　 ○（いつか / 近いうちに / そのうちに）一回、この農村で旅の準備をしましょう。 ×一旦・もしこの農村で旅の準備をしましょう。

Comment: What you said differs from what I feel as a native speaker, even though I know interpretation of words is not always determined to a single correct answer. I think this 一度 has no nuance of future. As they say この農村, they have arrived at the 農村 and are supposed to start 旅の準備 from now on. If they were leaving and planning to come back to the 農村, they would rather say 今度, though 一度 wouldn't at least be wrong.

Comment: ああ、「ひとまず」って感じですか・・・文脈がないとわからないですけど、そうかもしれませんね。文脈が欲しいところです。

Comment: そうですね。適切な説明が思いつかなくて困っていたのですが、「ひとまず」というのはいい言い換えだと思います。 Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On the link below 一度 can be interpreted as short for 少なくとも一度は which means "at least once"
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/3543/meaning/m0u/%E4%B8%80%E5%BA%A6/

So you could translate as:
一度この農村で旅の準備をしましょう。
At the very least, let's make travel preparations in this farming village.

Comment: 私もそういう感じの意味だと思って、一度回答したんですけど、OPからコメントでコンテクストを教えられて、そういう意味ではないとわかって、回答を削除したんです。コンテクストは⇒`As for context, in the story I was reading a party of travelers had just arrived at a town early in their journey and was looking to acquire any supplies they needed then head off. Sorry I didn't think further context would be necessary. I would appreciate it if you let me know how that alters your opinion, as you and the other poster are offering different interpretations.`　回答削除したせいで、コメントが見えなくなって、ややこしくて申し訳なかったです。